# Why does $\left(1+{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^\sqrt{n}$ also converge to $e$?

Tags: calculus

> Why does $\left(1+{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^\sqrt{n}$ also converge to $e$?

I mean, if we use, instead of $\sqrt{n}$, something like $2n$ or $n^2$, we could argue that these sequences are SUBsequences of $(1+1/n)^n$. I need a proper definition or explanation why these sequences are related to the "original" sequence of $e$. Is there something which tells are that these sequences (with $\sqrt{n}$, $2n$, $n^2$) are related to it?

I would appreciate an answer. If my question sounds trivial, I'm sorry. The explanation that all sequences $\sqrt{n}$, $2n$, etc are converging to infinity does not seem legitimate, as, for instance, $(1+1/(2n))^n$ converges to $\sqrt{e}$, yet both $2n$ and $n$ converge to infinity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $\sqrt n$ and $2n$ approach infinity, but not at the same rate.

Comment: You can write any $n$ as $m^2+k_m$ with $k_m$ satisfying $0\leq k_m\leq 2m$ we have $$\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{m^2+k_m}}{m+1}}\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+k_m}}\right)^{\sqrt{m^2+k_m}}\leq\left[\left(1+1/m\right)^{m}\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{m^2+k_m}}{m}}$$ Now observe how the two bases in the two sandwiching sequences tend to $e$ and the exponents tend to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can show that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x=e $$
where the above is a limit of a function.
Thus, for any sequence $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}=e $$ In particular, your limit is obtained by taking $x_n=\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can always make a substitution. For your first example, set $y=\sqrt n.$ Then as $n\to+\infty,$ we have that $\sqrt n\to+\infty,$ so that $y\to+\infty$ too. Then we have that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt n}=\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y\to e.$$

You can then see that this also works for any function $f(n)$ such that $f(n)\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)=e.$$
Likewise,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n}=e.$$

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of reals with $a_n\to\infty$. Then wlog. $a_n\ge 1$ for all $n$.
If $m_n\in\Bbb N$ with $m_n\le a_n<m_n+1$, then 
$$\left(1+\frac1{m_n+1}\right)^{m_n}<\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}< \left(1+\frac1{m_n}\right)^{m_n+1}.$$
Now given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ with $\left|\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n}-e\right|<\epsilon$ and 
$\left|\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n+1}-e\right|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. From $a_n\to\infty$, there also exists $M$ such that $a_n>N+1$ for all $n>M$. Then $m_n>N$ for all $n>M$ and hence $$\left|\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n} -e\right|<\epsilon$$
for all $n>M$. In other words,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e. $$

However, there is no reason to believe that $$\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{b_n} $$
converegs to $e$ or at all when $a_n\to \infty$ and $b_n\to \infty$ are *different* sequences.

Comment: exactly.SO: There hast to be a relation between $a_n$ and $b_n$. Im asking exaclty for that

Comment: @Maths If $a_n\to\infty$, then $(1+1/a_n)^{b_n}=[(1+1/a_n)^{a_n}]^{b_n/a_n}$. The base $(1+1/a_n)^{a_n}\to e$. Therefore, it is necessary and sufficient to have $b_n/a_n\to1$ to have $(1+1/a_n)^{b_n}\to e$.

Comment: I guess i got it. $a_n \in O(b_n)$

Comment: @Maths No $a_n\in O(b_n)$ is too weak. For example $2n\in O(n)$, but $(1+1/(2n))^n\not\to e$

Comment: it is not that easy if you have composition of sequences . $1+1/n$ converges to 1 but (1+1/n)^n does not converge to 1. But thanks mate been really very great

Comment: could we take instaed $o(b_n)$ ?

Comment: @Maths The case of something tending to $1$ raised to something tending to $\infty$ is an indeterminate case. However, something tending to $e$ raised to something tending to $1$ tends to $e^1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105553/discussion-between-maths-and-klstream).

Comment: @Maths No, the necessary and sufficient condition is $b_n/a_n\to1$ as I proved above.

Comment: which are the "determinate" cases could you tell me that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could prove it with L'Hoptial's rule. We have,
$$\ln\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right] = \frac{\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}.$$
Applying L'Hopital's rule, this approaches the limit of
$$\frac{-\frac{1}{2}n^{-3/2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}}{-\frac{1}{2}n^{-3/2}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \to 1.$$
Thus,
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}} = \exp\left(\ln\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right]\right) \to \exp(1) = e.$$

---

Now, I'm guessing that the above approach is somewhat unsatisfying. By the looks of it, you're trying to utilise the sequential definition of $e$ rather directly. By using logarithms and derivatives, I'm using heavier machinery than necessary, right?

Well, not really. There's a subtle complexity in this problem: raising the expression to the power of $\sqrt{n}$. For most $n$, this will be an irrational power, and it may not occur to ask yourself this, but what do irrational powers mean? Defining integer powers and rational powers is easy enough in terms of repeated multiplication and surds, but what about irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$?

The usual definition of a general real power is:
$$a^x = \exp(a \ln x).$$
Note that the definition uses both $\exp$ and $\ln$, both of which have to be defined in some way (usually one is defined, then the other is defined to be the inverse).

That is, you already need the exponential and logarithm functions defined just to pose the problem, before you even solve it! You're not going to find a solution to this problem that doesn't involve properties of these functions, in the same vein of proving the $2n$ and $n^2$ versions of this problem. So, you might as well lean into the useful theorems like L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too obvious.

$e^{√n(\log (1+1/√n))}=e^{√n(1/√n+O(1/n))}=e^{(1+O(1/√n))};$

Take the limit.